# Boostrap menu fill the width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need that the menu fills-in the width of its container instead of be left-aligned.

```
[LOGO A|B|C            ]
[LOGO   A  |  B  |  C  ]
```

Here is my test code. My question is how to achieve it using bootstrap.

```css
.navbar-brand{width: 405px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav table-responsive">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex-box`

```css
.navbar-brand {
  width: 405px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .navbar>.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
  }
  ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    flex: 1 1;
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    flex: 1 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav table-responsive">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: good candidate for the answer, thanks... I'll try in my example, then feedback

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this?

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    
     
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav table-responsive">
    <li class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need so set the `.navbar-nav` to `float: right;`, like this:

```css
.navbar-nav {
  float: right !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav table-responsive">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: why right? I neef to fill-in the space, I need `[LOGO   A  |  B  |  C  ]`, not `[LOGO             A|B|C]`

Comment: So you wan't more space between each menu item?

Comment: I want the menu items be justified, not left or right aligned

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```css
.navbar-header {width: 160px;}
.navbar-nav.table-responsive {
   width: calc(100% - 160px);
   border: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
   margin-right: 0;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
   float: left;
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left table-responsive">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: occupies two lines instead of one in full page view, also too much hard-coded values...

Comment: Thanks, now is better )

Comment: I am not sure which one you need. I have edited again to fill the entire divided width by nav item instead of floating in free space. If you want previous one, just use justify-content: space-between; instead of flex-wrap: wrap; and remove flex-grow: 1;